# What is the syntax to pass a function and it arguments to another function to execute it?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I have a `foo` function:

```
var foo = function(input) {
  console.log(input)
}
```

And a `bar` function:

```
var bar = function(fn, condition) {
  if (condition) {
    fn();
  }
}
```

I would like to pass `foo` as an argument of `bar` like: `bar(foo, true);`

The problem is that `foo` must be called executing a parameter.  If I use `bar(foo('param'), false);`, `foo` will be executed before `bar` starts and check the condition.

**Is there a better solution in JavaScript syntax?**

I know that I could modify my `bar` function to the following, but I don't want to modify the `bar` implementation:

```
var bar = function(fn, fnParam, condition) {
  if (condition) {
    fn(fnParam);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format: `bar(function() { foo(param); },false)`, unless you need the meta information in the foo function, like name, in which case you need to use the `function(fn, paramArray, condition)...` method

Note that with new Javascript features, such as [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you can write the same thing with `bar(()=>foo(param),false)`, but not all browsers support this syntax.

Comment: Great! That's not so readable as I would expect, but is good enough!

Comment: `->` is not an arrow function, `=>` is.

Comment: You're right. Fixed the typo.

Comment: @kimb: If your function doesn't need the `this` value to be set by the caller, you can do `bar(foo.bind(null, param), false)`